# How to prevent OWASP ZAP scanner hitting external URLs in Standard Mode?

Tags: owasp, zap

I am new to OWASP ZAP. I ran a automated scan in Standard Mode on my own website hosted on localhost (http://127.0.0.1:8000) with both traditional and AJAX spiders.

There are some external public URLs in the localhost website which are not under http://127.0.0.1:8000 like CDN's etc. Yet ZAP's Information Window shows them:

1. The Spider tab shows the external URLs Flagged as Out of Scope.
2. The AJAX Spider tab shows some external URLs returned 403 Forbidden.
3. The Active Scan tab shows content-signature-2.cdn.mozilla.net at the bottom.

Did ZAP actually "scanned" those external URLs? If yes, then how to prevent this from happening? Can this cause some kind of legal issue?

Thanks.

Comment: @simon-bennetts can you please throw some light on this question?

Comment: *Can this cause some kind of legal issue?* -- As explained in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ***Legal questions, including questions about copyright or licensing, are off-topic for Stack Overflow.*** Please either [edit] your question to remove that, or delete your question and ask at [law.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ZAP keeps scanning unnecessary URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514833/zap-keeps-scanning-unnecessary-urls)

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX Spider is not hitting those URLs - the requests are made from the browsers which ZAP launches and ZAP is returning the 403s.
ZAP will permit requests for JavaScript files (and I think CSS ones too from memory) as blocking these breaks many apps. However these are just standard requests that any browser would make - ZAP does NOT attack URLs that are out of scope.